# What information about me is visible with shareable links?

Tags: google-drive, privacy, google-drive-sharing

If I distribute a shareable link for a file in my Google Drive, what information about me is visible to those who click on the link?

I want to share some .mid file via shareable link, which allows people to download the midi file, but I don't want them to be able to see my information (name, email, etc.) in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared Google Drive files could be added to "My Drive"  by people that has access to the file and from there they are able to see the name of the file owner, but not their email address. Also they could see the a broad description of the activity done on the files.

From [View activity & file versions](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045?hl=en)

> See changes made to your files in Drive and keep track of who made those changes. You might see changes when someone:
>
> - Edits or comments in Google Docs
> - Renames a file or folder
> - Moves or removes a file or folder
> - Uploads a new file to a folder
> - Shares or unshares an item

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pretty anonymous... can you tell anything about me from this link?

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-qnf0ZyXmbD1aGVlfM73OPdv3j-hyICWbWnyPmym1v8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What's awesome is that when I reopened the document, it clearly had some visitors. 
[link](https://imgur.com/a/vsjyE)

Comment: *I* can't tell anything about you from that link, but I'm not really an expert, so I just wanted to make sure someone who knows more about it than I do wouldn't be able to find my info.

Comment: @AllenJackson So, this potentially answers the question in spirit, but it would be a much better answer if you showed why (e.g., is the URL just a hash or does it in fact contain info, etc.).